# Bootstrap-datepicker Displayed selected date is changed to today's date

Tags: javascript, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

The displayed selected date is changing to today's date when I'm submitting my form. Sometimes when I click whenever in the page. Here is part of the code involved:

html:

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <td>Fecha:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="fecha_generacion" name="fecha_generacion" class="datepicker form-control" style="width: 180px;" readonly></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

javascript:

```
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        autoclose: true,
        language: 'ES'
    }).on("changeDate", function (e) {
        if('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
            // console.log('Genial, tenemos un navegador decente que soporta LocalStorage');
            objDatos = localStorage.getItem('objDatos');
            objDatos = JSON.parse(objDatos);
            fecha_generacion = $("#fecha_generacion").val();
            objDatos.fecha = fecha_generacion;
            objDatos_stringified = JSON.stringify(objDatos);
            $("#objDatos").val(objDatos_stringified);

            localStorage.setItem('objDatos', objDatos_stringified);
            console.log("Fecha actualizada en localStorage");
        } else { 
            alert('No soporta LocalStorage. Actualize el navegador !!'); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the version of the bootstrap-datepicker that you use? And can you provide a jsfiddle with a full working example?

Comment: Hi acrobat. thanks for answering. I can't get the version of the bootstrap-datepicker i'm using but it is this one: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker
about the jsfiddle here's the link https://jsfiddle.net/24v9n1h6/ I hope it can help you to help me. regards